Python Jenkins CICD pipeline setup module error
I was trying to setup a Python Jenkins CICD pipeline and understand how it works. Then deploy the same on docker for practice on End-to-End deployment.
I get the following error when trying to do existing setup from a repo that was mentioned in a blog post.
Summary of what the error is : Module imp not found and the process breaks.
I initially thought it was related to setup.py in the repo which had the instructions for Python setup on Jenkins localhost but when I went through the log found that it was from library module that was getting installed.
ERROR MESSAGE LOGS:
This is where the error comes when after getting the scipy pkg:
[
      14:30:42  + pip3 install -r requirements/dev.txt
      14:30:42  Collecting Click==6.7 (from -r requirements/prod.txt (line 2))
      14:30:42    Using cached click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (424 bytes)
      14:30:42  Collecting numpy==1.14.3 (from -r requirements/prod.txt (line 5))
      14:30:42    Using cached numpy-1.14.3.zip (4.9 MB)
      14:30:42    Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
      14:30:43    Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      14:30:43  Collecting scipy==1.0.1 (from -r requirements/prod.txt (line 6))
      14:30:43    Using cached scipy-1.0.1.tar.gz (15.5 MB)
      14:30:43    Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
      14:30:44    Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
      14:30:44    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      14:30:44    
      14:30:44    × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
      14:30:44    │ exit code: 1
      14:30:44    ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      14:30:44        Traceback (most recent call last):
      14:30:44          File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
      14:30:44          File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
      14:30:44          File "/tmp/pip-install-l5j04co1/scipy_4df4228396dd4dc38b4e7c2e7bb1e6f0/setup.py", line 418, in <module>
      14:30:44            setup_package()
14:30:44          File "/tmp/pip-install-l5j04co1/scipy_4df4228396dd4dc38b4e7c2e7bb1e6f0/setup.py", line 346, in setup_package
14:30:44            write_version_py()
14:30:44          File "/tmp/pip-install-l5j04co1/scipy_4df4228396dd4dc38b4e7c2e7bb1e6f0/setup.py", line 140, in write_version_py
14:30:44            FULLVERSION, GIT_REVISION = get_version_info()
14:30:44                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
14:30:44          File "/tmp/pip-install-l5j04co1/scipy_4df4228396dd4dc38b4e7c2e7bb1e6f0/setup.py", line 116, in get_version_info
14:30:44            import imp
14:30:44        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
14:30:44        [end of output]
14:30:44    
14:30:44    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
14:30:44  error: metadata-generation-failed
14:30:44  
14:30:44  × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
14:30:44  ╰─> See above for output.
14:30:44  
14:30:44  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
14:30:44  hint: See above for details.

]
I am following the instructions on the blog and trying to deploy the pipeline step-by-step whichever ones apply for me.
any idea where I can find the File "/tmp/pip-install-l5j04co1/scipy_4df4228396dd4dc38b4e7c2e7bb1e6f0/setup.py" since I cant find it anywhere in the GITHUB repo? or is the error popping up due to some other issue?
not sure what file to add as reference , is the setup.py file sufficient?
TROUBLESHOOTING STEPS:
I initially thought it was related to setup.py in the repo which had the instructions for Python setup on Jenkins localhost but when I went through the log found that it was from library module that was getting installed.
so tried to change the installer package from pip to pip3 to see if that would help but still had the same error.(Based on the earlier answers that were provided for similar issue so figured version mismatch might be the issue so tried to update the installation)
Think the code works for most part since the python installation is triggered by pipeline process but is unable to download the packages needed for installation.
Is this like issue with NETWORK ACCESS ISSUE ON MY END since I am trying to configure Python on my localhost using the pipeline so it should be a clean installation & configuration should be done by the pipeline(and no prior versions of python should conflict with the installation)
